# Google analytics and Event names

Tags: google-analytics

For Event Tracking, is it necessary to first add event categories, actions and labels in admin or these can be added in code (as documentation suggests)? If not necessary to add in admin, what's to stop someone from spamming analytics with useless categories/actions via Web Console or node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no admin option to define acceptable event categories, actions and labels.  This is all done at the code level via _trackEvent.  Whatever you place in the event tracking call will show up in GA.

As you mention, visitors could fire event tracking code within the console.  From my experience, this is not very common or much of an issue to worry about.  You have the same issue with custom variables and even pageview tracking (firing a virtual pageview).

You can use profile filters in GA to target and manipulate event data (exclude, include, etc).